# How to display nested JSON object in grid panel?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, extjs, extjs3

My code is like this for store which I have to display in grid

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore(
                                {
                                    name: 'approverlist',
                                    autoLoad: true,
                                    url: 'json/loginLogout.do?Uid=' + userLdapId + '&startDate=' + selectedStartDate + '&endDate=' + selectedEndDate,
                                    root: 'loginAndLogoutTime',

                                    fields: ['employeeId', 'fullName', 'email', {name: 'weekDate', type: 'String', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].weekDate'}, {name: 'dayOfWeek', type: 'String', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].dayOfWeek'},
                                        {name: 'inTime', type: 'float', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].inTime'}, {name: 'outTime', type: 'float', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].outTime'},
                                        {name: 'totalHours', type: 'float', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].totalHours'}, {name: 'attendenceStatus', type: 'String', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo[0].attendenceStatus'},
                                    ],
                                    listeners: {
                                        load: function(store, records, options) {
                                            alert("Store");
                                            alert("Store" + store.getTotalCount());


                                        }

                                    }
                                });
```

My grid code:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                            width: 1250,
                            height: 500,
                            title: 'View Login And Logout Details',
                            store: store,
                            trackMouseOver: false,
                            disableSelection: true,
                            loadMask: true,
                            // grid columns
                            columns: [{
                                    id: 'ldapuid', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Employee ID",
                                    dataIndex: 'employeeId',
                                    width: 50,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Employee Name",
                                    dataIndex: 'fullName',
                                    width: 50,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Employee Email",
                                    dataIndex: 'email',
                                    width: 100,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Date[dd-mm-yyyy]",
                                    dataIndex: 'weekDate',
                                    width: 50,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Day Of Week",
                                    dataIndex: 'dayOfWeek',
                                    width: 50,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "In Time",
                                    dataIndex: 'inTime',
                                    width: 100,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Out Time",
                                    dataIndex: 'outTime',
                                    width: 100,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Total Hours",
                                    dataIndex: 'totalHours',
                                    width: 25,
                                    sortable: true
                                },
                                {
                                    id: 'topic', // id assigned so we can apply custom css (e.g. .x-grid-col-topic b { color:#333 })
                                    header: "Attendence Status",
                                    dataIndex: 'attendenceStatus',
                                    width: 50,
                                    sortable: true
                                }],
                            // customize view config
                            viewConfig: {
                                forceFit: true,
                                enableRowBody: true,
                                getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, p, store) {
                                    if (this.showPreview) {
                                        p.body = '<p>' + record.data.excerpt + '</p>';
                                        return 'x-grid3-row-expanded';
                                    }
                                    return 'x-grid3-row-collapsed';
                                }
                            },
                            // paging bar on the bottom
                            bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                                pageSize: 25,
                                store: store,
                                displayInfo: true,
                                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                                emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
                                items: [
                                    '-']
                            })
                        });
```

My JSON format is like this:

```
{"totalcount": 1,"loginAndLogoutTime": [{
  "departmentId": 0,
  "swipeCardInfo": [
    {
      "transationType": null,
      "attendenceStatus": "Weekend",
      "inTimeVsOutTime": [
        "<td> - </td><td> - </td>"
      ],
      "totalHours": 0.0,
      "inTime": null,
      "outTime": null,
      "weekDate": "05 April 2015",
      "dayOfWeek": "Sunday"
        },}
```

How can I get nested JSON object in my grid panel? I am not able to understand that. In my page it is displaying `employeeId` `fullname` and `email` but `swipecardINfo` object is not being displayed.

Comment: {name: 'swipeCardInfo', type: 'auto', mapping: 'swipeCardInfo'} will map as an Array all your swipeCardInfo items

Comment: thanks for ur reply,Yes it will map as array but how can i map dynamically all the details? My code is like this--

Comment: Would be better to have the code of your grid :)

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to load all swipeCardInfo in one store ? because actually you load only one object with multiple swipeCardInfo in it. If you get only your swipeCardInfo you will not have an array but multiple object in your store

Comment: I updated tags  so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it and improved the formatting for better readability.

Comment: Yes,It was difficult to show that way.So I changed my json object structure with only swipecardInfo object to display as I wanted to display data in my grid.Thankx for ur quick response..:)